# Prototype.js 1.7: using collect with explicit function returns different results than with inline function, why?

Tags: javascript, hash, filter, prototypejs

Consider this hash in Javascript:

```
> a = { 80450: "915", 111931: "930", 111938: "", 1234: null, 5678: undefined }
```

and this function which should return only values that parse to an integer value > 0:

```
> $H(a).values().filter(function(x) { return x; }).collect(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
[915, 930]
```

This seems correct. But this

```
> $H(a).values().filter(function(x) { return x; }).collect(parseInt);
[915, NaN]
```

*should* do the same thing (shouldn't it)? It doesn't. Tested on Chrome 31 and Firefox 25. Is this maybe a bug in Prototype?

Side question: Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collect()` method expects a iterator function type, and while normally when you pass a closure with one parameter only the first parameter is used

```
collect(function(x){
   //function body
});
```

however collect is really passing 2 parameters to the iterator function

```
collect(function(value,index){
    //function body
});
```

which when you put `parseInt()` in as the iterator with the function definition of `parseInt(string,radix)` you get

```
parseInt("915",0);  // => 915
parseInt("930",1);  // => NaN as radix 1 doesn't make sense
```

Comment: OMG, it's the old "value" vs "key,value" hair-pulling contest again. Thanks - I feared it would be something like this ...